# Alaska Airlines 737-9 MAX door plug row?

Tags: boeing-737

What row is the door plug, that detached during flight 1282, located near on an Alaska Airlines 737-9 MAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2024/01/09/business/boeing-737-max-bolts.html) article shows it as row 26.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was watching Blancoliro's channel and his description. and it's like any lift out style plug door. There were supposed to be stop bolts installed in the roller tracks at the top so the door couldn't be manually opened or removed, but I don't see how even with those bolts missing the door could find its way up on its own. As soon as the pre-pressurization sequence starts on the takeoff roll, if it's half or one psi, that's up to a ton or so pushing on the thing to hold it where it is. At 14000 ft the cabin is about 5 psi, so maybe 10 tons plus. It's a strange story.